# Why can't my neural network model's accuracy be improved on this training set?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have a simple training set with 3 classes, and the accuracy is always 1/3=0.333... Can someone explain why this network always has 1/3 accuracy on this set?

I made my own implementation of training a neural network and it seems like that if I use a high epoch value(like 500), the output will be [0.333.., 0.333.., 0.333..] on any input, so I thought something was wrong with the implementation, but using keras(see below) seems to give the same result.

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
x_train = np.array([[1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,2], [2,3], [3,3],
                    [4,2], [4,4], [4,5], [3,5], [5,2], [5,3], [5,4], [6,1], [3,6], [6,4],
                    [5,0], [6,0], [3,-1], [4,-1], [5,-1], [6,-1], [3,-2], [4,-2], [5,-2], [6,-2]], dtype=float)

y_train = np.array([[1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,0],
                  [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0], [0,1,0],
                  [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1], [0,0,1]], dtype=float)

x_train[:10,0] = x_train[:10,0] - 5
x_train[10:20,:] = x_train[10:20,:] + 5

# normalization
x_train[:,0] = (x_train[:,0] - np.average(x_train[:,0]))/np.amax(x_train[:,0])
x_train[:,1] = (x_train[:,1] - np.average(x_train[:,1]))/np.amax(x_train[:,1])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10)

# plot
plt.scatter(x_train[0:10,0], x_train[0:10,1], marker='x')
plt.scatter(x_train[10:20,0], x_train[10:20,1], marker='o')
plt.scatter(x_train[20:30,0], x_train[20:30,1], marker='+')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try tuning your hyperparameters, for example using 'tanh' activation function in `tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='tanh')` instead of 'sigmoid' in the first layer of the model increases the accuracy from 0.333 to 0.667. You can also try to add various layers.
You can check out this [link](https://missinglink.ai/guides/neural-network-concepts/7-types-neural-network-activation-functions-right/) for details on activation functions

Answer (score 0):

since you have a classification model:

1. You should add a `Softmax` layer as your last layer.
2. make sure of your labels to be one hot encoded  (binary vectors). you can use `to_categorical()` Keras method on your labels. I see you already have a binary vector though the data type is float. But I think it works as it is. so the first step is more important for your problem.